# Geometry - Intersection over Union for 2 squares with the same orientation

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have 2 squares with the same orientation. I know the coordinate of their centers. They have the same size area.

They may intersect each other. I want to compute their area of their intersection as well as area of their union.

Let's say that their centers are (a, b) for the first square and (x, y) for the second square. The length of one of their sides is l. How can I compute their intersection and their union based on this?

Comment: You could first try to draw an image of the possible cases and come up with at least a few ideas. besides ... this definitely has at least a few duplicates... 'intersection rectangles' has more than 4800 occurances in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they have the same orientation, you can rotate the two squares first so their sides are aligned with the x, y coordinates, then it should be easy to compute what you want.